# How do I one-hot encode features using Cloud ML?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

How do I one-hot encode features using Cloud ML? Do I have to do this in the TensorFlow model, or can I do it in the Cloud ML SDK itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preprocessing (CsvFeatures), use:

features.categorical('passenger_count')

You can also pass in a frequency threshold to avoid one-hot encoding values that occur too infrequently in the data.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you'll need a bit more to pick the kind of representation you want - one of k (or one-hot) or sparse.

```
features.categorical('passenger_count').one_of_k()
```

Side note, you might also be interested in numerical columns, and the ability to apply a log (often useful for count type of features) or discretization via bucketing.